# pyscript display error - exposing white space

Tags: python, pyscript

I'm studying pyscript these days.
I tried to execute the following HTML code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>>
        <script type="py">
          print("Hello, World!")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But, this code is executed like the following picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A63T7.png)
Can I get rid of the white part of the result?

I could not find any information about this on the internet.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div style="width = 300px; height = 300px;">
        <script type="py">
          print("Hello, World!")
        </script>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I tried to use div tag to set a range of the space, but this didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

[Starting in version 2022.12.1](https://jeff.glass/post/whats-new-pyscript-2022-12-1/#Display), writes to stdout (like `print` etc) are routed to a `<py-terminal>` element [as described here](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/plugins/py-terminal.html). The decision was made since writing to standard out is a simple linear stream of text, whereas there are many more places and ways on a page that you might want to place the output from a Python script.

To send content from Python to a specific place on the page, use the [`display`](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/API/display.html) built-in function. Without a `target` argument, the values passed to `display()` will appear in the same location as the `<py-script>` tag itself; the `target` argument takes the ID of a DOM element to send the output to.

Alternatively, you can add the `output` attribute to a `<py-script>` tag (also the ID of an element in the DOM) to send all output to stdout to the element in the DOM with that idea. See the [`<py-script>` tag reference](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/elements/py-script.html) for details.